# numpy array argsort not sorted correctly

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Environment: Python 3.6.5, Jupyter 4.4.0
Working with scikit-learn lda and attempting to sort the component topics; however, I'm encountering consistently odd results using argsort()

My debug code is:

```
testArray = np.array([4.09999998, 0.1, 0.10000539, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.10000231, 0.1, 0.10000264, 0.1, 0.1, 0.10000064, 0.1, 0.10000592, 0.1, 0.10000874, 4.70374711, 0.1, 0.10000692, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.10000971, 0.1, 0.1, 0.10000581, 0.1000008, 0.10000729, 0.1, 4.099977, 12.76810792, 0.1, 2.47658459, 4.09995712, 0.10001568, 0.10000793])
print(testArray)
print(testArray.argsort())
```

the variable testArray contains the following:

```
[4.09999998  0.1         0.10000539  0.1         0.1         0.1
  0.10000231  0.1         0.10000264  0.1         0.1         0.10000064
  0.1         0.10000592  0.1         0.10000874  4.70374711  0.1
  0.10000692  0.1         0.1         0.1         0.10000971  0.1
  0.1         0.10000581  0.1000008   0.10000729  0.1         4.099977
 12.76810792  0.1         2.47658459  4.09995712  0.10001568  0.10000793 ]
```

testArray.argsort() returns:

```
[17 23 21 20 19 28 31 14 24 10 12  7  5  4  3  1  9 11 26  6  8  2 25 13
 18 27 35 15 22 34 32 33 29  0 16 30]
```

however, that's not the correct sort sequence. If I dump topic into a spreadsheet and sort it, I get the following sequence:

```
[30 16  0 29 33 32 34 22 15 35 27 18 13 25  2  8  6 26  
11  1  3  4  5  7  9 10 12 14 17 19 20 21 23 24 28 31]
```

Is this a bug? Or do I need to use a different approach to sort a numpy array of floats? ...Yes, I've already searched StackOverflow and not found any questions on this issue.

capture from excel shows the data: 
[image: It works so much better when I don't mess up the excel macros]

Comment: Can you please post an example with fewer numbers, say.... 5?

Comment: ... or at least one where the number of values in `topic` and `topic.argsort` is the same :D

Comment: updated with shorter example

Comment: numpy is sorting lowest to highest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no bug.

0.1 occurs most number of times, which can appear in an arbitrary order when `argsort` is used. As far as the larger numbers are concerned, the numpy order is ascending while the excel order appears to be descending - the last few indices in the numpy order is the same as the first few in the excel order.

Comment: you're right ... numpy is ascending - and I was assuming descending. urrrgh. thanks.